# Click more than 3 times TextView, App gets crashed

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout, crash-reports, android-logcat

I have 2 `TextViews` inside `RelativeLayout`. I have put `clickable=true` to my `RelativeLayout` so that when clicked `RelativeLayout`, both `TextViews` are highlighted. I have not set an `Intent` to my `RelativeLayout`. When I click one time, it is not crashing but the problem is, When I **immediately** click more than 3 times RelativeLayout it is crashing. 
In LogCat it is written: `E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering`
Anybody who has faced such problem and fixed??
My XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="127dp"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_ne_ne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:text="@string/qayerdan"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/light_dark"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_qayerdan_tanlash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tanlash"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_ne_ne"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:textSize="19sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_ne_ne2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:text="@string/qayerga"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onCLick"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_ne_ne"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/light_dark"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_qayerdan_tanlash2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tanlash1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_ne_ne2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:textSize="19sp" />
```

JAVA CODE:

```
    public class DelHome extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_del_h);


        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Drawable d = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.menu, null);
                toolbar.setNavigationIcon(d);
            }
        });
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_buyurt_yar) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_bosh_sahifa) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_call_centre) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_biz_haqimizda) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_foyd_shartlar) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_chiqish) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code,,,

Comment: Add your source code

Comment: Already done. Nothing in java. only OnCreate Method

Comment: are you setting any ripple effect anywhere?

Comment: Thats why I am wondering. I am not using any Ripple effects, but in the logcat it is saying about Ripple))

Comment: Please guys, help me to fix it?  I would appreciate your help

Comment: check my answer..

Comment: could show your 'onCreate()' codes?

Comment: @ZafarKurbonov post your java code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to set your `RelativeLayout`'s background ? With something like this :

With creating **background_ripple.xml** in drawable resources :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@color/grey_light"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and settup it in your `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="127dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_ripple"
    android:clickable="true">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit** : With something like this, Android may render a ripple effect

I hope this will help you

Comment: Let me apply this. I will let you know @MrLeblond

Comment: Thanks bro, It works now. I dont have a crash!))))))))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that Better to Perform **Build → Rebuild** project

**OR**

Go with the **Invalidate Catch and Restart**

Comment: Cleaned and Rebuilt projet but results are worse : Now with one click it is crashing((
I did Invalidate Catch and Restarted, again not helping((((

Comment: Why this is happening I dont know) I dont have my own java code, all is only onCreate method of android custom code. nothing i have added in the code

Comment: did you check your build.gradle ??

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'

Answer (score 0):

```
android:onClick="onCLick"
```

Since your java does not have any functions named OnClick, try deleting this line. Maybe it triggers internal calls